# MFC error "Failed to create an empty document" in Release mode only

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, runtime-error

I run an application under MFC/SDI and Visual Studio 2008.

I get the error "Failed to create an empty document" in the Release mode only. I found that the offending code is that I show you below. The error triggers ONLY when the input parameters is an email string ie xyz@yahoo.com. Also in the debug mode it works just fine.

Can someone give me an explanation why this happens ?

```
void CUtils::RemoveEndingSlash(CString *str) {


    if (str->GetAt(str->GetLength()-1) == '/') {

        *str = str->Left(str->GetLength() - 1);

    }

}
```

The exact offending code is

```
str->GetAt(x).
```

I solved the problem changing the above code using the input parameter by value instead by reference.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Ok solved.

Buffer overflow, because some callers before they passed an empty string.

I had not check for empty string and thus I got buffer overflow.

Comment: Do you know why there was no error in the debug mode?

Comment: I am sorry, but I really don't remember anything :-(