# MFC "Failed to create empty document" only in debug setting in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

When I run my MFC SDI application, the *"Failed to create empty document"* pop-up message occurs at startup *only* in the debug setting. I checked this question ([MFC error "Failed to create an empty document" in Release mode only](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36775854/2287576)) but couldn't get any hint.

It seems that 'clean solution' (function in Visual Studio) should be done to reproduce this difference between the default debug/release setting.

I also found that `CFrameWnd::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct)` fails in `CMainFrame::OnCreate`:

```
// MainFrm.cpp
int CMainFrame::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{   
    if (CFrameWnd::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1) {
        ::AfxMessageBox(_T("Failed.")); // <- this message is shown right before the "Failed to create empty document" message.
        return -1;
    }
    //...
}
```

What could be the causes of this problem?

And how the configuration setting(debug/release/etc.) can affect this?

Thanks.

---

Edit:
Thanks to @xMRi and @IInspectable's advice, it seems that `vector.reserve(100'000'000)` in my custom view's `OnCreate`(i.e. `CmyView::OnCreate`) was the cause of the above error message. I changed the value to 10'000'000 and the error message does not pop up anymore. The exact type of that vector is `std::vector<std::vector<CString>>`.

So, I guess memory shortage was the problem. FYI, I used 32-bit setting in Visual Studio, in Windows(x64).

I set a breakpoint on that line(`vector.reserve`) and used "step into", and I saw this comment:

> // destroy [_First, _Last), choose optimization
> // note that this is an optimization for debug mode codegen;
> // in release mode the BE removes all of this

I don't know what `BE` means, but it seems that this kind of differences between debug/release mode in Visual Studio made the aforementioned error message pops up only in debug mode.

Any additional advice would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Check if the view is created.

Comment: This usually happens when the view failed to be created. What kind of view are you using?

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the `OnCreate()` call and *"Step Into"* the code. This will eventually lead you to the initial issue that caused the upper levels to fail. You may have to disable the *"Just My Code"* debugger option.

Comment: @xMRi I used `CView`. I checked my code, at least `CView::OnCreate` returns fine, but... Oh, while I was writing this comment, I found that the error message described in the post is shown at the line `std::vector::reserve(100'000'000)` in the `OnCreate` of my custom view. Changing the value to 10'000'000 removed the error. I was using 32bit setting in Visual Studio, in Windows. Maybe out of memory was the culprit...? Thanks for your advice, I'll modify the question to mention this. Any further advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks, I tried it but a problem occurred: _"winfrm.cpp not found: Source link authentication failed"_. I also applied your advice to "step into" the code at the line of `vector.reserve(100'000'000)` in the `CmyView::OnCreate` (probably the cause of the error as I commented above) and it was helpful! But again the same type of error  _"wincore.cpp not found: Source link..."_ occurred. I think I should somehow fix this. Could you give me any advice on this? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you use such a great reserve value? Does this make sense?

Comment: @xMRi If you're asking if the application really needs that much reserve value, not always. But sometimes it receives lots of data from the server during a very short period of time and it should operate in real-time. So I wanted to reserve a sufficient memory for the vector to contain all the data from the server, without possible delay from reallocating a new contiguous memory block.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You are wasting memory. You are wasting energy. You cause the system to reserve data and the system may swap out memory... Let the std lib do the job. 
Reallocating is much faster than receiving the data from the server. Again: It doesn't make sense. You don't believe me: Profile it....

Comment: Moreover, since you intend to store the data in `CString`, the allocations that happen during the individual `CString` construction will outweigh the `vector` allocation by magnitudes.

Comment: @xMRi Thanks, you're right. And I did profile using VS profiler. I just tried reserving since it should be faster(or not slower) at least "theoretically" and also many people in this community recommend it for optimization, but I agree with you. As you know, this question is not about that, it's about the error message I described. Thanks for your help:)

Comment: @j6t Ah, that's also what I think. Sadly, the thing is, `CString` itself is the raw data I receive from the server, because I have to use a 3rd party app to receive the data. Any advice would be great. Thanks.

Comment: @xMRi Oh, when you said _"the system may swap out memory"_, you mean the "swap memory" which means the OS lets the disk(SSD or HDD) to hold some data since there's not enough memory, right? Thank you. I didn't think about that. Please let me know if I misunderstood what you said. (P.S. If I use sufficiently big (say 32GB) RAM, would it be still a problem, even if it's a 32-bit app? I guess 4GB is already a limitation so memory swapping using disk wouldn't happen easily. This is just a question though.)

Comment: You probably don't have the MFC source code installed, and the debugger attempted to download the source code from Microsoft's source server (which you do not have access to). You need to install the MFC source code to enable the debugger to step into it. It's available as an optional component in the Visual Studio Installer.

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you. I tried installing it as you advised, but it seems I already installed all the MFC-related stuff and also the recent version of the Windows SDK. My VS still complains it can't find source code such as `xlock.cpp`(not MFC code I think). How about creating the cpp file by myself by copying the code from [Microsoft STL repository](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/src/xlock.cpp)? Or is there any legitimate way to get the Microsoft STL implementation so that the debugger can work fine? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: If the debugger cannot find a source file, it allows you to search for it. *xlock.cpp* is part of Visual Studio's CRT implementation, located under *<VS Install Dir>/VC/Tools/MSVC/<version>/crt/src*.